# Make a sticky navbar in salesforce1

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, css

Elements with styles `position: fixed` doesn't seem to get sticky when you view it in salesforce1. It works fine on desktop but not on salesforce1. The closest clue I got is salesforce creates a different code structure for its own header (which is sticky) and encloses your actual codes in a series of divs wherein a scrollerJS is taking effect (which probably works similar to an iframe).

Is there a way to somehow make element's positioning fixed? Or a documentation covering this one?

Comment: Is this related to Salesforce1 in general, or Salesforce1 on iOS/Apple?

Comment: salesforce1 in general. Tried using android, salesforce1 simulator and chrome emulator, they all got this specific behavior that I don't get on desktop version

Answer (score 1):

SLDS has a component called [Global Header](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/global-header/). It can be used a your reference to achieve what you want.

> The global header is the anchor for the Salesforce platform and spans
>   all other parts of the UI. **The functionality in the header is
>   applicable across all contexts in the Salesforce ecosystem**

You can play with this. Make sure you add SLDS as resource.

```
<header class="slds-global-header_container"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-assistive-text slds-assistive-text--focus">Skip to Navigation</a><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-assistive-text slds-assistive-text--focus">Skip to Main Content</a>
  <div class="slds-global-header slds-grid slds-grid--align-spread">
    <div class="slds-global-header__item">
      <div class="slds-global-header__logo">
        <img src="/assets/images/logo-noname.svg" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-global-header__item slds-global-header__item--search">
      <div class="slds-form-element slds-lookup">
        <label class="slds-assistive-text" for="global-search-01">Search Salesforce</label>
        <div class="slds-form-element__control lookup__search-control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon--left">
          <svg class="slds-input__icon" aria-hidden="true">
            <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#search"></use>
          </svg>
          <input type="search" id="global-search-01" class="slds-input slds-lookup__search-input" placeholder="Search Salesforce" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="slds-global-header__item slds-grid slds-grid--vertical-align-center">
      <li class="slds-grid">
        <button class="slds-button slds-button--icon slds-button--icon-container slds-button--icon-small slds-global-header__button--icon-favorites" title="Toggle Favorite">
          <svg class="slds-button__icon slds-global-header__icon" aria-hidden="true">
            <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#favorite"></use>
          </svg>
          <span class="slds-assistive-text">Toggle Favorite</span>
        </button>
        <span class="slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger--click">
          <button class="slds-button slds-button--icon slds-button--icon-container slds-button--icon-small slds-global-header__button--icon slds-m-left--none" aria-haspopup="true" title="View Favorites">
            <svg class="slds-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">
              <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#chevrondown"></use>
            </svg>
            <span class="slds-assistive-text">View Favorites</span>
          </button>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li class="slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger--click slds-p-horizontal--xxx-small">
        <button class="slds-button slds-button--icon slds-button--icon-small slds-button--icon-container slds-button--icon-x-small slds-global-header__button--icon-actions slds-m-horizontal--xx-small" aria-haspopup="true" title="Global Actions">
          <svg class="slds-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">
            <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#add"></use>
          </svg>
          <span class="slds-assistive-text">Global Actions</span>
        </button>
      </li>
      <li class="slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger--click">
        <button class="slds-button slds-button--icon slds-button--icon-container slds-button--icon-small slds-global-header__button--icon" aria-haspopup="true" title="Help and Training">
          <svg class="slds-button__icon slds-global-header__icon" aria-hidden="true">
            <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#question"></use>
          </svg>
          <span class="slds-assistive-text">Help and Training</span>
        </button>
      </li>
      <li class="slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger--click">
        <button class="slds-button slds-button--icon slds-button--icon-container slds-button--icon-small slds-global-header__button--icon" aria-haspopup="true" title="Setup">
          <svg class="slds-button__icon slds-global-header__icon" aria-hidden="true">
            <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#setup"></use>
          </svg>
          <span class="slds-assistive-text">Setup</span>
        </button>
      </li>
      <li class="slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger--click">
        <button class="slds-button slds-button--icon slds-button--icon-container slds-button--icon-small slds-global-header__button--icon" aria-haspopup="true" title="Notifications">
          <svg class="slds-button__icon slds-global-header__icon" aria-hidden="true">
            <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#notification"></use>
          </svg>
          <span class="slds-assistive-text">Notifications</span>
        </button>
      </li>
      <li class="slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger--click slds-m-left--x-small">
        <button class="slds-button" title="person name" aria-haspopup="true">
          <span class="slds-avatar slds-avatar--circle slds-avatar--medium">
            <img src="/assets/images/avatar2.jpg" alt="person name" />
          </span>
        </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: I already tried this one. It's still scrolling along with the other contents.